# How to downgrade a Qnap Nas firmware ?

Tags: network-attached-storage, qnap

after installing last qnap firmware, our nas go very slow. 
How to recovery and downgrade with a 'lower' firmware ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading can be done the same as upgrading.  Simply download the new firmware and re-flash it via the web interface.  There's an option for uploading a custom binary on the same page as the automatic upgrade.